# Convert incoming byte stream into integers and export to Excel

Tags: excel, arduino

I am very new to programming and am working on an Arduino project to measure wavelengths of light.

I am using the [Spectruino 3](http://myspectral.com/spectruino-installation.html) and am trying to read in the bytes that it records into an array, convert the array into an integer array and then export that data to excel. Currently I have this:

```cpp
const int numBytes = 501;
int bytestream[numBytes]; 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0; i<numBytes; i++){
    bytestream[i]=Serial.read();  
  }
}
```

My spectrometer currently doesn't work, but this seems to compile. I was just wondering how to convert this `bytestream` array into an integer array and then export it into Excel.

Comment: How are you going to transfer the data to your PC? Do you have a serial connection or do you use a memory card or other media?

Comment: Yes, it's just a usb connection from the device to the PC

Comment: Please don't say *just* USB connection. *Universal* Serial Bus has [four transfer types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#System_design), and from those have been derived [dozens of device classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes). What USB device is it when it's plugged in?

Comment: It's a com port on device manager if that's what you were looking for - sorry I'm very new to this!

Comment: That device seem to be able to send the data directly to the PC via USB. What's the point of that Arduino code, that most of the time just reads -1?

Comment: Hi gregor, why does it just read -1? All i want is for the data from this device to be in an integer format so I can use it later. Thank you!

Comment: Read the [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read).

Answer (score 0):

Excel and other, better spreadsheet programs can load text file based CSV files.

That means you have 2 options:

1. Convert data to CSV rows in device.
2. Send text data over serial line and use any serial port program on PC that can receive to file to catch the data.
3. Open CSV file in Excel or other, better spreadsheet program.

Or

1. Send raw binary data over serial line and use any serial port program on PC that can receive to file to catch the data.
2. Convert data to CSV file with your favorite scripting language (like Python).
3. Open CSV file in Excel or other, better spreadsheet program.